# How to get 3 image links per line instead of 2, on mobile

Tags: html, wordpress, css

I am trying to get my page to show 3 image links per line on mobile, instead of two, which is what currently shows. If you view this site in the developer tools as an iPhone 5, you'll see there are two square image links per line. I'd like to get 3 images per line, but am not sure what CSS rule to change to get three.

I tried modifying the width of various Divs, but it only made the image links smaller, and did not bring the third up to the line.

http://50.87.248.154/~thetinat/search/

Please let me know if I can clarify anything. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to reduce width to: `width: 29%;` and turn off `clear: both;` on the `odd` class.

Like so:[image]

```
.odd {
  clear: none;
  float: left;
}

.recipes-bottom .featuredpost .post {
  width: 29%;
  margin: 20px 5px 0px;
}
@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .recipes-bottom article, .home-middle article {
    float: none;
    clear: none;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 150px;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
}
```

Comment: This looks great, thanks! Only it seems to be working for a few lines, not all of them. If you scroll down on the page you'll see the images get out of whack, something like this: http://imgur.com/pEtps2p

Any thoughts?

Comment: This should fix it: 
`article {
  float: none;
  clear: none;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 150px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}`

You probably want to put it inside a media query, like:

`@media (max-width: 480px) {
  article {
    float: none;
    clear: none;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 150px;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
}`

Comment: Thanks! That fixed the 3-in-a-line issue, but it is also affecting other widgets, like this: http://imgur.com/uRTMcN4. Is there a way to assign what you suggested to only the articles in a specific widget area (.recipes-bottom and .home-middle)?

Comment: Sure! Since `recipes-bottom` and `home-middle` are outer divs, just change the css to `.recipes-bottom article {`. Et cetera.